# Media Query not behaving properly between normal desktop and responsive design mode, why?

Tags: css, layout, css-grid

This is the project:https://xvicissitudex.github.io/Basic_Website_Template/

```css
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.zone {
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #FFF;
  font-size: 2em;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: 1px solid #bbb;
  transition: all 0.3s linear;
}

.blue {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat( auto-fit, minmax(350px, 1fr));
  grid-gap: 20px;
  padding: 20px;
}

figure {
  background-color: hsla(0, 0%, 20%, 1.0);
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0px;
}

figure>img {
  width: 30%;
  padding: 1rem;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1132px) and (max-width: 1501px) {
  figure:last-child:nth-child(3n-1) {
    position: relative;
    left: 55%;
  }
  figure:nth-last-child(2):nth-child(3n-2) {
    position: relative;
    left: 55%;
  }
}
```

```html
<section class="zone blue">
  <figure><img src="img/data_storage_2_2.png"></figure>
  <figure><img src="img/desktop_analytics_2.png"></figure>
  <figure><img src="img/files_2.png"></figure>
  <figure><img src="img/monitor_coding_2.png"></figure>
  <figure><img src="img/monitor_settings_2.png"></figure>
  <figure><img src="img/server_2_2.png"></figure>
  <figure><img src="img/server_3.png"></figure>
  <figure><img src="img/server_safe_2.png"></figure>
</section>
```

The idea is to center the left over grid items in the blue zone. When I go into responsive mode on Firefox everything is fine.However, when responsive mode is off, this media query seems to start at 1115 instead of 1132 like I put in the code, why is this?

Answer (score 1):

This seems to do the trick, but I have no idea why at that very specific dimension the browser decides to put a scrollbar.

body { scrollbar-width: none; }

Answer (score 0):

works fine if you remove the scrollbar

```
body::-webkit-scrollbar { //for chrome
   width: 0px; 
}
```

Comment: Thanks, did not work for me but pointed me in the right direction. This is what worked for me:

body {
   scrollbar-width: none;
}